# Spring security: extract subject from jwt in SecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get subject from principal.

Currently, I'm using this code:

```java
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
    String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
} else {
    String username = principal.toString();
}
```

In fact, `principal` object class is `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt`.

Nevertheless, I was expecting to get the subject of jwt, instead of that I'm getting whole token.

My current configuration works well. I mean, I can authorize methods using `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

My current configuration is:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(
    HttpSecurity http
) throws Exception {
    Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> oauth2Customizer = (config) -> config.jwt();
    return http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/gicar/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Customizer)
        .build();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no other custom configurations and your token is instance of `JwtAuthenticationToken`, the subject can be directly extracted from the token itself.

```java
String subject = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

According to [JwtAuthenticationToken](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/abe68abfe4862905c2e11193514762d79e490e4b/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationToken.java#L37) and [JwtAuthenticationConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/abe68abfe4862905c2e11193514762d79e490e4b/oauth2/oauth2-resource-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/authentication/JwtAuthenticationConverter.java#L35)